# Why is there infinite recursion when I apply a function with the argument n-1 (no parentheses), inside the application of another function?

Tags: haskell

Here I can pass to function `f` the argument `7-1`, without parentheses.

```
Prelude> f = (+1)
Prelude> f 7-1
7
```

**1.**
Why is the following an infinite recursion?

```
Prelude> addRec :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a; addRec 0 = 0; addRec n = n + addRec n-1;
Prelude> addRec 5
```

**2.**
I can fix it by either adding parentheses to `n-1`

```
Prelude> addRec :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a; addRec 0 = 0; addRec n = n + addRec (n-1);
```

**3.**
Or by using the `$` operator with parentheses on the whole `addRec` recursion term:

```
Prelude> addRec :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a; addRec 0 = 0; addRec n = n + (addRec $ n-1)
```

I'd like to understand *exactly* how each expression works or doesn't work.

Here is my line of reasoning:

In `addRec n = n (...)` we are effectively composing two function (without using the `.` composition operator). We are composing `(+)` and `addRec`. Is Haskell in this example understanding we have a third function `(-)`?

We are using function application (which as far as I understand is the operator represented by a whitespace after a function) to achieve this composition.

Function application is left associative, so my first question is: what does `addRec n = n + addRec n-1` look like when we add the parentheses corresponding to the default left associativity?

Comment: Function application takes priority over all other operators. `addRec n-1` is parsed as `(addRec n) - 1`. You can only fix that with explicit parentheses, or the `$` operator.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This is not a typographical error, but a (very common) misunderstanding of Haskell's operator precedence rules.

Comment: It may not be a typographical error, but I don't believe it needs yet *another* answer that explains basic precedence rules. I thought there was a discussion in meta that indicated trivial questions that can be addressed by a simple comment could be included under "no longer reproduced".

Comment: @chepner I disagree that this is a "trivial" question, since if it was there would likely be a duplicate. Besides, what may be trivial to one person is not necessarily trivial to another. And I also disagree with justifying closing a question with an incorrect reason based on some discussion on meta. If SO want to formally introduce a justification for closing a question because it is trivial that's fine, but until then downvoting a question (as "not useful") is more appropriate than voting to close for a bogus reason.

Comment: I think it's *so* basic that there is not a single duplicate, but there are various questions which boil down to the same fundamental problem: not understanding precedence. There probably *should* be a single, canonical question dealing with this, but I'm not sure how best to frame it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f 7-1` doesn't mean what you think it means.

In Haskell, function application has the highest priority. This means that `f 7-1` is always interpreted as `(f 7) - 1`. The absence of a space around the minus sign is irrelevant, and it is only by coincidence that you get the correct answer: `f 7 = (+ 1) 7 = 8`, and then `8 - 1 = 7`. This would not happen if your function was defined as `f = (* 2)`.

Similarly, `addRec n-1` is interpreted as `(addRec n) - 1`, thus calling `addRec` with the same argument `n` every time, producing infinite recursion.

The two ways to fix it, you already know: parens or operator `$`.